# How to show dynamic image with server side vapor swift?

Tags: swift, server-side, vapor, leaf

i just newbie and want learn more about server side swift with vapor, now i am really stack on the show image dynamically with vapor swift. in my case. i have image on folder :

public -> images -> a.png , b.png

and i have name of image on my database, and i want to make get requests for show image on leaf file, with parameter name of my image, how to implement thats. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create route like so:

```
drop.get("route") { request in
    return try self.drop.view.make("path/to/somepage", ["myimage": "/images/a.png"])
}
```

And in your `somepage.leaf`:

```
<img src="#(myimage)">
```

Comment: @Gomfucius, i have written this code but i got error. Is it write?  drop.get("route") { request in
    return try drop.view.make("http://localhost:8080/", ["myimage": "/CSImages/GumoStyleM15.png"])
}